# Ways of splitting CPU-Bound tasks to avoid blocking other asyncio tasks

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm pretty new to asyncio, correct me if my terminology is wrong.

 Suppose I have a CPU-bound task that runs a for loop.

 I have another task that pings every 1sec.

 If we initiate both, the CPU-bound task will block the pinging task.

 How do split the CPU-bound task so as it doesn't block the pinging task.

 Currently I only have a dumb way of doing this, which is to divide the CPU-bound task into 1000 pieces and sleep 1sec after finishing every 1 piece.

 Any better solutions to this?

 Thanks

```
import time
import asyncio

async def ping():
    print(f'ping - {time.time()}')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f'ping - {time.time()}')

async def process():
    result = 0.0
    print(f'process - {time.time()}')
    for i in range(100000000):
        result += i * i
    print(f'process - {time.time()}')
    return result

async def run():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(ping())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(process())
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)

asyncio.run(run())
```

The output of the above code follows

```
ping - 1659977867.4815755
process - 1659977867.4816022
process - 1659977874.5827787
ping - 1659977874.5828712
ping - 1659977875.5845447
ping - 1659977876.5862029
ping - 1659977877.5878963
ping - 1659977878.5894375
```

Comment: You should look at asyncio's `run_in_executor` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: any feedback please?